# How can I create these grooves?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I want to model the grooves on this gun:

[image]

What's the best way to go about this? I want to know how to do it with booleans as well as how to do it without booleans. The challenge is that this gun part is round instead of flat and curves inward towards to the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

**Boolean**:  First add solidify modifier to the gunstock.   Make a cylinder ("cutter") with a diameter larger than the stock, near the shoulder, the height of a single crosscut.  Then use a shrinkwrap to the gunstock and add solidify modifier to the depth of the cut. add an array modifier. All but the leftmost cut that appears to be a different that I would do separately.

[image]

here is the blend of my example: [image]

Comment: It almost works. The issue is that the solidify modifier will be applied on all 3 dimensions. So for example, there will be some space between the cut and the original gun stock. This issue is more apparent if you apply the scale of the cutter cylinder.

This is a problem because I don't want there to be a cut on the top of the gun, just along the bottom and the sides. 

Lastly, it fails if I apply rotation of the cutter object for some reason.